# What is the natural way to refer to in-laws of an unexpected gender?

Tags: vocabulary, korean-culture, word-choice

If my father's sister has a husband, I call him 고모부.

If my father's younger brother has a wife, I call her 숙모.

If my father's sister has a wife, what do I call her? If my father's younger brother has a husband, what do I call him?

I understand that these family structures are not common in Korea but maybe one of these sounds more reasonable than another to a native speaker, or perhaps there is some alternate phrase that makes more sense.

Even better would be a more general rule or practice, if there is one.

Comment: How can his sister have a wife and brother have a husband?

Comment: @user17915 I would imagine the sister is a lesbian and the brother is gay. That seems to be the entire premise of this question.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Just a heads-up. Your edit clearly conflicts with the OP's intention.

Comment: We've got a bad edit pending here. EDIT: Nevermind, @Rathony beat me to it.

Comment: By the way, gay marriage is still not legal in Korea. So there would be no proper word to describe them. 고모의 아내, 삼촌(숙부)의 남편 can be used substitutely.

Comment: @jungyh0218 Sometimes people who live in Korea have to talk in Korean about people who live outside of Korea and follow different laws.

Comment: @jungyh0218 To be fair, whether something is *legal* has little to do with vocabulary.

Comment: I support gay marriage too. It is a tragedy that there is no word to describe them... New Korean words are usually made and admitted by National Language Institute. I think they don't want to make a word about LGBT issues. It is a very shameful thing.

Answer (score 3):

There wouldn't be a simple single word that someone of Korean cultural assumptions would understand to mean what you want.
You'd probably have to be explicit and say 고모의 와이프/고모의 아내 for 
'Father's sister's wife', and or 삼촌 의 남편/삼촌 의 바깥분 for 'Father's younger brother's husband'.

Of course within the family or among people who are familiar with the situation, it might be possible to agree on something shorter and more convenient. For example, '고모부' could be an amusing pun for 'father's sister's *wife*', because 부 can be a Chinese character representation for a character 夫 meaning husband, AND a character 婦 meaning wife - as in the word [부부](http://hanja.naver.com/word?q=%E5%A4%AB%E5%A9%A6), meaning 'husband and wife'. Just to be clear, this would not be understood unless you were 'in on the joke' - 고모부 in general means father's sister's *husband*.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if I understood the question properly, but I tried searching for a chart that shows family structure in as much detail as possible, but it seems surprisingly hard to find

Here are some of the resources I found online that shows this information in relatively more detail (the more detailed resources are in Korean, the English versions are not as much detailed )

http://totalog.net/2054#.V3FcNtJ97IU

In the page linked above, search for 친가의 호칭
This table lists the words used for family relations within one's own house (father, mother, fathers siblings, father's parents, one's children, brothers, sisters, etc)

It also lists the titles to be used in the household of own's fathers sister (고모 집안의 호칭), titles to be used in the mother's home(외가의 호칭) etc

A dictionary might be helpful here

Some other websites with a bit more detailed information:

http://rhyshan.com/141

http://tip.daum.net/question/50678807
(search for the post with the text 상황1) 여기는 우리집. 오늘은 주로 친가쪽 친척들이 모였을 때 호칭 )

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - the link doesn't seem to include the lesbian/gay relationships that OP's question is specifically about.

Comment: Adding to what @dotVezz said, I don't think you understood the question. Please read it again.